# How to show the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected" view error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, http-request, server-error, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 view, and have a question in regards to detecting a `HttpRequestValidationException`.

Here is the controller code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestView()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestView(TestModelViewModel testModelViewModel)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Here is the view code:

```
@model CanFindLocation.ViewModels.TestModelViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestView";
}

<h2>TestView</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtExpiryMonth">Expiry Month</label>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="txtExpiryMonthDivClass">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtExpiryMonth" name="ExpiryMonth" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

I can enter in some HTML code as follows in the ExpiryMonth form control:

```
<html>
```

The `<html>` code is currently permitted to be in the form control, and the following error is NOT shown after the submit button is pressed:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (name="").
>
> Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is
>   potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script.
>   The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your
>   application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of
>   input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a
>   web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A
>   potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
>   (name="").
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

How do I PREVENT users from entering in malicious code? When I scaffold a controller, with views (my above code is NOT done from scaffolding), the above error is displayed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I do not want to allow a user to enter in HTML code, I wish to prevent a user from entering in HTML code. How do scaffolded views do this? What code do I need to add to my view/controller so that the error page is shown when HTML code is entered in the view?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 0):

The application is doing exactly what it should do. The field does not allow HTML, so if someone posts HTML, there's a server error. This is a perfectly valid response. If the user is jacking around with the request data, then it's appropriate to return a server error.

Comment: There is no server error. The user CAN enter invalid data. That is the problem. How can i PREVENT the user from entering invalid data and thus show the error?

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your post action and add htmlencode to your code

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Comment: How do views that are scaffolded perform the check for malicious code?